# Curl in Java for authentication for moltin api

Tags: java, curl

I am trying to authenticate with the moltin api using curl in Java, and I am using the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb;
pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "curl",
        "-d ",
        "\"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={id}&client_secret={secret}\"", "https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token");

pb.directory(new File("/Users/ateleb/Downloads/docs-master/test"));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
```

However, this is giving me an error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=id&client_secret=secret"
```

Please note that i do replace the id and the secret with my appropriate keys and they do work using the command line.

Any help in figuring out what i am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put the "-d " and the "grant_type ..." into one parameter of ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://moltin.com/getting-started/curl, the authentication request is

```
curl -X POST https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token \
  -d "client_id=XXXX" \
  -d "client_secret=XXXX" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Each string pass to the `ProcessBuilder` constructor represents one argument. Try the followings:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "curl",
        "https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token" 
        "-d", "client_id=XXXX",
        "-d", "client_secret=XXXX",
        "-d", "grant_type=client_credentials");
```

Comment: Don't put hyphen before POST, and it can be run into one as `"-XPOST"` -- or omitted because it's the default when `-d` is used; Don't use quotes within an argument (shell removes them but Java doesn't, causing curl to send the wrong data) and when run together don't use a space for the same reason (either `"-d", "client_id=xxx"` or `"-dclient_id=xxx"`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for your comment